# In LDS doctrine, why isn't repentance possible without eternal punishment?

Tags: lds, punishment, repentance

> **[Alma 42:16](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/alma/42.16?lang=eng#15)**
>
> Now, repentance could not come unto men except there were a
>   punishment, which also was eternal as the life of the soul should be,
>   affixed opposite to the plan of happiness, which was as eternal also
>   as the life of the soul.

Why is repentance not possible without *eternal* punishment? I understand why punishment must exist (it's explained well in the chapter), but it doesn't explain why the punishment must be *eternal*.

Answer (score 4):

There are similar discourses elsewhere in the Book of Mormon, notably in  2 Nephi 2 and 2 Nephi 9.  Especially in 2 Nephi 9:6-8 it is explained that without the atonement of Christ, the judgement that came on Adam would have been eternal and unending, but not why that is a precondition for repentance.

> [2 Nephi 9:6-8](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/9.6?lang=eng#5)
>
> 6 For as death hath passed upon all men, to fulfil
> the merciful plan of the great Creator, there must needs be a power of
> resurrection, and the resurrection must needs come unto man by reason
> of the fall; and the fall came by reason of transgression; and
> because man became fallen they were cut off from the presence of the
> Lord.
>
> 7 Wherefore, it must needs be an infinite atonement—save it should be
> an infinite atonement this corruption could not put on incorruption.
> Wherefore, the first judgment which came upon man must needs have
> remained to an endless duration. And if so, this flesh must have laid
> down to rot and to crumble to its mother earth, to rise no more.
>
> 8 O the wisdom of God, his mercy and grace! For behold, if the flesh
> should rise no more our spirits must become subject to that angel who
> fell from before the presence of the Eternal God, and became the
> devil, to rise no more.

It appears that Alma is using "repentance" as shorthand for the plan of redemption including repentance, as summarized in Alma 42:13. Otherwise, this particular verse is difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 3):

[D&C 19](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/19.4-12?lang=eng#) has a really interesting explanation of the meaning of *eternal* that may also apply to its usage in Alma:

> 4 And surely every man must repent or suffer, for I, God, am endless.
>
> 5 Wherefore, I revoke not the judgments which I shall pass, but woes shall go forth, weeping, wailing and gnashing of teeth, yea, to those who are found on my left hand.
>
> 6 Nevertheless, it is not written that there shall be no end to this torment, but it is written endless torment.
>
> 7 Again, it is written eternal damnation; wherefore it is more express than other scriptures, that it might work upon the hearts of the children of men, altogether for my name’s glory.
>
> 8 Wherefore, I will explain unto you this mystery, for it is meet unto you to know even as mine apostles.
>
> 9 I speak unto you that are chosen in this thing, even as one, that you may enter into my rest.
>
> 10 For, behold, the mystery of godliness, how great is it! For, behold, I am endless, and the punishment which is given from my hand is endless punishment, for Endless is my name. Wherefore—
>
> 11 Eternal punishment is God’s punishment.
>
> 12 Endless punishment is God’s punishment.

In other words, as I understand these verses, *eternal* punishment does not mean a punishment that has no end, but punishment that is dealt out by God. *Eternal* is "more express" "that it might work upon the hearts of the children of men" for God's glory (v. 7).